# Path between nodes query never finishes

Tags: c#, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I've created a graph in CosmosDB with two vertex types, an actor vertex and a movie vertex. The only edge type that exists is an "acted in" type. You can imagine the graph as having many actors and many movies and any given actor may have acted in any number of movies.

I am trying to write a query that will discover and return the path between two actors. For example, Keanu Reeves acted in the Matrix with Laurence Fishburn. Laurence Fishburn acted in the movie Apocalypse Now with Marlon Brando. Therefore, the path between Keanu Reeves and Marlon Brando is Keanu Reeves -> The Matrix -> Laurence Fishburn -> Apocalypse Now -> Marlon Brando.

This is the query that I've come up with.

```
g.V('keanureeves')
.repeat(both().simplePath())
.until(hasId('marlonbrando'))
.path()
.limit(1)
```

The query works for small graphs. I can query and construct the path. However, once I get to a certain graph size, the query times out and never finishes.

I am using the CosmosDB emulator locally, not the real CosmosDB on Azure. It's hard to say how many documents are in the database because the emulator UI doesn't give me a way to query for a count.

Can I speed up my query without changing my data model? If I do have to change my data model, what might work better? I'm new to graph databases and Gremlin.

Edit: It seems to happen between 1200 and 1300 documents. Under 1200 documents, results return. Here's the breakdown of document types:

```
540 movie vertexes
112 actor vertexes
681 actedIn edges
```

Edit #2: I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.Graphs NuGet package and it looks like the method I'm invoking is throwing an OutOfMemory exception. My code:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string gremlinQuery)
{
        var query = _documentClient.CreateGremlinQuery(_graph, gremlinQuery);

        var results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var feed = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            results.AddRange(feed.Select(x => x));
        }
        return results;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.GetTaskForResult(TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.NextAsync()
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.ScalarSubqueryFunction.<EvaluateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.PathOperator.GetStepProjectionResult(FieldObject step, Int32& activeByFuncIndex)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.PathOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.SimplePathOperator.<NextAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.PathOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.RepeatOperator.<NextAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.PathOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.RangeOperator.<NextAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.GraphTraversalIterator.<CurrentOperatorNextAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.GraphTraversalIterator.<MoveNextAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal.<MoveNextAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GremlinDocumentQuery`1.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Octogami.SixDegreesOfNetflix.Application.Data.GremlinClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext() in C:\dev\SixDegreesOfNetflix\Application\Data\GremlinClient.cs:line 28
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Octogami.SixDegreesOfNetflix.Application.Data.ActorPathRepository.<GetPathBetweenActors>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\dev\SixDegreesOfNetflix\Application\Data\ActorPathRepository.cs:line 20
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Octogami.SixDegreesOfNetflix.Application.Feature.GetPathBetweenActorsCommandHandler.<Handle>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\dev\SixDegreesOfNetflix\Application\Feature\GetPathBetweenActors.cs:line 42
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Octogami.SixDegreesOfNetflix.Website.Controllers.ActorController.<DegreesOfSeparation>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.GetTaskForResult(TResult result)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.<NextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.ProjectOperator.NextAsync()
    at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.ScalarSubqueryFunction.<EvaluateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()<---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 0.2.4-preview Nuget package, the limit() clause was not behaving correctly. In the 0.3.0-preview Nuget package, an optimization was added for the limit() traversal step. When I updated the package, my problem was solved.

See the changelog on the [Graph SDK page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-sdk-dotnet).